# arrayList for(int data:) checkout iteration times

Tags: java, for-loop, foreach

Maybe this is a stupid question, but i still wonder

if i use

```
ArrayList<Integer> Data=new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int data:Data)
 //some code here
 //print out the iteration times
```

i want to print out the iteration times (not the execution time)
*without using*

```
for int i;i<blahblahblah;i++) output i
```

for example output

```
output:
This is iteration times: 1   the data is : blahblahblah
This is iteration times: 2   the data is : blahblahblah
This is iteration times: 3   the data is : blahblahblah
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this may not be correct asthetically

```
ArrayList<Integer> Data=new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int data:Data)
{
   System.out.println( Data.indexOf(data)+1 );
   Data.remove(Data.indexOf(data));//to ensure the index is correct even if there are duplicates
}
```

since for each loop accesses the elements sequentially it will give you the iteration number = (index + 1)

**Edit:**
If you can remove the element you can ensure that the duplicates problem will not occur. Or else the traditional for loop is best suited

Comment: Ha, not only is this inefficient but it could be incorrect if the list has duplicates.

Comment: Yup, this is the answer i want ! Although still using the indexOf method, but duplicate problem =(

Comment: @PaulBellora : doesn't matter if list has duplicates. we have to print number of iterations remember !

Comment: @PaulBellora yup,I'm serious, i want this instead of using a new int interation=0, i want the spirit of this method, so any suggestion?

Comment: @Huei Yeah, stop being lazy :)

Comment: @Huei : I guess paul is right the output would be wrong if there are duplicates but still a plausible option if you can ensure non duplicates in your list

Comment: i can't giv u the acception right now, seems can be another better answer, sry but thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

One way would be: Define a counter variable outside the loop and increment the counter.

```
ArrayList<Integer> Data = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int iterCnt = 0;
for (int data : Data) {
    iterCnt++;
    System.out.println(iterCnt);
}
```

Comment: I don't think there is another way unless you use legacy for loop. I may be wrong too. Let us wait and see for other members response too.

Comment: I think this is the only other method, I might be wrong though. Btw: The enhanced (for each) for loop uses an iterator right?

Comment: @Bucco: Yes, that is correct. Enhanced for loop uses iterator.

Comment: too bad, maybe can someone improve this in the next JAVA generation 
i just want a pretty code but seems not right now
Thanks all =)

Comment: Isn't the whole point of an iterator so that you do not have to deal with index incrementing though?